# Is there a way to view when the last time a record was viewed?

Tags: 2003

Im migrating 2003 SharePoint sites over to 2013, and I wanted to know which to keep and which not to....

I know there is a way to view when the Record was last modified, but is there a way to view when the last time a list or record was viewed? So I can see if users are still using the list...
or is there a way to view when the site was last accessed?

Comment: what do you mean from MSDN? I am the admin, but how do i access it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to look at your [usage statistics](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc288233(v=Office.12).aspx).

Site level:  (from MSDN)

1. On the site you want to view data for, click Site Settings.
2. Under Administration, click Go to Site Administration.
3. Under Management and Statistics, click View site usage data.

Site Collection level:

1. On the top-level Web site of the site collection, click Site Settings.
2. Under Administration, click Go to Site Administration.
3. Under Site Collection Administration, click View site collection usage summary.

Comment: but will this only work to see who made a change or who actually opened the list and viewed it?

Comment: That's just usage, generally (an aggregate figure).  Knowing who opened and viewed items is generally a customization even in later editions of SharePoint. I don't think it would be found in 2003, just who created, edited, deleted documents and that's at the document level (not at the site or library level)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you enable the auditing on your site collection then you can check when a document last modified/views etc.

check this blog for more information: http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.com/2013/07/audit-logging-in-sharepoint-2013.html

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want this on the 2003 server, so 2013 answers do not help.

You could use the IIS logfiles to see what URLs were accessed. Maybe have to rework the data a bit to get the info you need.

I did this to figure out which sites were important and needed to be migrated first to a 2007 environment.
As I recall we used Access because the data did not fit in Excel.
Tables were linked to CSV files, we could create a daily report with a view clicks.
We probably did this because the SP2003 reporting wasn't of much help.. *but don't shoot the messenger*... this was over 8 years ago.